# Node.js Potential Memory Leak which Exceed 1.8G Limitation

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, imap, email-parsing

I have a Node.js application which check and retrieve emails every 15 minutes. I'm using `node-imap` and `mailparser`. When I tested I found the memory seems leaked. My process memory increased from 50MB to 2.3GB after it kept running a night.

Here came some questions to me.
1, I knew Node.js has memory limitation (actually it's v8 limitation) which is about 1.8G in x64 system. But my application used 2.3G. Why it happened? Does this mean it's the memory out of v8 was leaked?
2, I attached `memwatch` module and tried to figure out the reason. But after running my application for 30 minutes I can see the memory was increased from 50MB to 200MB but `memwatch` didn't fire `leak` event. Does this mean there's no memory leak? Or it's because non-v8 memory was leaked but `memwatch` cannot detect?

I am new to Node.js performance tuning and memory analyse so any ideas would be appreciate.

Thanks,

**Update**
I used `heapdump` to dump snapshot after each time the application retrieving emails. Then I got 4 snapshots and when I compared them, "String" is most increased category (same result from `memwatch.diff`. In Chrome Dev Tool all of them are marked as "parent in (sliced string)". So I'd like to know what's this mean. And why it cannot be GCed since it just a local variant inside my function which was invoked every time I need to check mail.